# lightning:select onchange to access other field of object array

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, lightning-community

I have lightning component which contains picklist which holds list of Assets and onchange function i need to access other fields of object which returns from Apex controller. Can you please help me for same.

## MarkUp

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,
                            flexipage:availableForRecordHome,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,
                            force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,forceCommunity:searchInterface,
                            force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader"
                access="global" controller="modifyOrder">
    
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="assetInfo" type="Asset[]" />
    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    
    <lightning:select aura:id="currAssets" label="Select Assets" 
                        value="{!v.assetName}" onchange="{! c.assetChange }">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.assetInfo}" var="item">
            <option  value="{!item.Name}"> {!item.Name}</option>    
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:select>
</aura:component>
```

## Controller

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        
        var action = component.get("c.getAssets");
        
        action.setParams({"woId": component.get("v.recordId") });
        
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.assetInfo", response.getReturnValue());
                component.set("v.assetName", component.get("v.assetInfo[0].Name"));
            } else {
                console.log('Problem getting Aseet Information, response state: ' + state);
            }
        });
        
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
        
    assetChange: function (component, evt, helper) {
        //I need to print other fields of Asset coming from Apex Controller.
    }
})
```

## Apex

```
public with sharing class modifyOrder {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Asset> getAssets(Id woId) {
        
        WorkOrder wo = [SELECT Id, AccountId from WorkOrder WHERE Id = :woId LIMIT 1]; 
 
        String AssetQuery = 'SELECT id, AccountId, Name, SerialNumber '
                            + 'FROM Asset WHERE  AccountId =  \'' + 
                            String.escapeSingleQuotes(wo.AccountId)+ '\'';
        
        List<Asset> woLine = Database.query(AssetQuery);
        
        return woLine;
    }
}
```

Comment: You already have `assetInfo` populated on component in `doInit` function that contains the return value from Apex, you just need to print it. Is there an issue that you are facing?

Comment: @JayantDas basically i don't which index i need to use?

Comment: It depends on whichever you need to be printed. But you have the data already available.

Comment: lets suppose, We have 3 assets A1 with Serial No S1, A2 with S2 and A3 with S3. By default picklist is set to A1 which is at 0 index, but when i change to A3, I need to access S3, but i don't at which index it's stored. I know, there is indexVar in aura:iteration but i don't know, how to use and will it be useful or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> We have 3 assets A1 with Serial No S1, A2 with S2 and A3 with S3. By default picklist is set to A1 which is at 0 index, but when i change to A3, I need to access S3

You need to access the `Asset` detail corresponding to the `Name` that's selected in your picklist.

You can achieve it by one of the ways that I have found useful is to create a `Map` of the values returned from your Apex controller. So you will need to declare a `Map` in your component, say as:

```
<aura:attribute name="assetMap" type="Map" default="{}" />
```

Now, in your `doInit()` function, where you are getting the `Asset` details in the callback from Apex, you populate it as:

```
component.set("v.assetInfo", response.getReturnValue());
component.set("v.assetName", component.get("v.assetInfo[0].Name"));

// create map of asset name as key, and the asset object as value
var assetMap = new Map();
for (var i = 0; i < assetInfo.length; i++) {
    assetMap[assetInfo[i].Name] = assetInfo[i];
}
component.set("v.assetMap", assetMap);
```

And then, in your `assetChange()` function, you can retrieve the details from the `Map` as:

```
var assetMap = component.get("v.assetMap");

// this will now return you the Asset object in the map, 
// and its serial number corresponding to the asset name that was selected
var serialNum = assetMap.get[component.get("v.assetName")].SerialNumber;
```

This is just a sample, adjust as you need, but this approach will get you there.

Comment: Thanks Jayant... i will try this approach and will let you know...

Comment: Thanks Jayant. this also solve my problem. But i also found that IndexVar in aura:iteration that also solve my problem.